# How to display long list of names alphabetically?

Tags: lists, names

I've got a pretty large amount of names to display on a webpage (~150). I was thinking maybe I could display 40 or so per page, but I have no clue how to do this without it looking hideous, as the list of names is pretty much the only content on the page, and a first and last name wouldn't really take up much space. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the purpose of the list? How is it used?

Comment: It's just a webpage that shows everyone who contributed money to a donation group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using multiple columns to maximize the available space:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvG8gv.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

If there is any way to group the donors (perhaps by how much they have donated) you could further break the list up into more manageable pieces:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faItmj.png)</sup>